# Question about abelian C*-algebras and the corresponding Gelfand transform: $C_{0}(\Sigma)$ or $C(\Sigma)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, gelfand-representation

In [Murphy](https://books.google.nl/books?id=omviBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), Theorem 2.1.10, they say that any **abelian non-zero  C*-algebra $A$** is $\ast$-isomorphic to $C_{0}(\Sigma_{A})$, where $\Sigma_{A}$ is a maximal ideal space.

In [Conway](http://users.math.uoc.gr/~nikosf/FunctionalGrad2015/Conway.pdf), Corollary VIII.2.2, they say that an **abelian C*-algebra $A$ without unit** is $\ast$-isomorphic to $C_{0}(\Sigma_{A})$. (And Theorem VIII.2.1 says that a unital abelian C*-algebra $A$ is $\ast$-isomorphic to $C(\Sigma_{A})$.)

Why doesn't the literature agree with each other? In particular: why doesn't Murphy need 'non-unital' and why doesn't Conway need 'non-zero'?

*Recall: $C_{0}(X)$ is the space of continuous functions that vanish at infinity.*

Comment: If $A$ is unital $\Sigma_A$ is compact and $C_0(\Sigma_A)=C(\Sigma_A)$, so Murphy's statement is correct regardless of whether $A$ is unital or not

Comment: As for the non-zero thing: You could ask yourself whether you consider $C(\emptyset)$ (consisting of exactly the empty map) should be considered a $C^*$-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an Abelian $C^\ast$-algebra then $A$ is $\ast$-isomorphic to $C_0(\Sigma_A)$, if $A$ is unital then $\Sigma_A$ is compact and so we also have that $C_0(\Sigma_A)=C(\Sigma_A)$. The statement in Conway's book is phrased in a weird way, since the "without unit" is superfluous, maybe he wanted to stress that in the unital case you can use $C(\Sigma_A)$ instead, even though it makes no difference.

As for the zero $C^\ast$-algebra it is a matter of convention, if $A=\{0\}$ then $\Sigma_A=\varnothing$ and $C(\Sigma_A)$ only contains the empty function so it could be considered as a zero dimensional vector space and be isomorphic to $A$, but for example some authors insist on a topological space being nonempty, so they'd exclude this, I'm not sure about the conventions used in Murphy's book.